# Why is my GID environment variable empty?

Tags: environment-variables, groups, uid

I try `echo $GID` but get nothing. However, I can get 1000 by using `id -g`, what's the differences between them ?

```
id -u     => 1000
id -g     => 1000
echo $UID => 1000
echo $GID =>
```

The output of `id`:

```
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare),999(docker)
```

The output of `groups`:

```
user adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you're using bash as your shell. Bash doesn't set a `GID` variable. The [list of Bash variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) mentions `EUID` and `UID`, but not `GID`.

Zsh, on the other hand, [does set `GID`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-GID):

```
$ bash -c 'echo $GID'

$ zsh -c 'echo $GID'
1000
```

Comment: What's the differences between using `bash -c 'echo $GID'` and `echo $GID` in terminal ?

Comment: @Corey `echo $GID` in my terminal would run it in zsh, since I use zsh as my shell. In your terminal, it might be run in bash. I use `bash -c ...` to run the command specifically in bash.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Is there any way in bash to get `GID` except `id -g` ?

Comment: @Corey use command `cat /etc/group | grep ^your_group_name | cut -d: -f3`

Comment: Is it a good idea to use `$GROUPS` as a replacement ?

Comment: @Corey if you're using bash, possibly. But I don't know if it's guaranteed to hold your GID as the first element of the array.