# What environment variable will report the user's primary group

Tags: bash

The `$USER` reports the current username. But what group(s) do they belong to and specifically which is their primary group : ie. if the user creates a new file the group ID that would be applied as part of the file ownership attributes.  Is there an environment variable or if not a shell command to obtain that identifier?

Comment: I don't think there is a conventional environment variable for that - however you can use the `id` command ex. `id -gn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no conventionally recognised equivalent to `$USER` for a user's primary group - however you can use the `id` command. From `man id`:

```
   -g, --group
          print only the effective group ID

   -G, --groups
          print all group IDs

   -n, --name
          print a name instead of a number, for -ugG
```

So to get the primary group name, use `id -gn`. You can wrap it in a command substitution `$(id -gn)` if you need something that you can use like a variable.

---

Note that *some* shells set a `GID` variable for the numeric id of the primary group - see for example [Why is my GID environment variable empty?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124674/why-is-my-gid-environment-variable-empty)